# Why can't I increment a variable according to the value of i in a for loop in python

Tags: python

```
import math
head=int(input(""))
legs=int(input(""))
max_dogs=math.floor(legs/4)
dogs = 0
chicken= head-dogs  
for i in range(0,max_dogs+1)
    dogs==i 
    if legs == dogs *4 + chicken *2:    
        print(f"dogs are {i} and chicken are {head-i}")
```

This was a code I wrote to find out the number of dogs and chickens present if the number of heads and legs in the location is provided.(chicken=2 legs, dogs=4 legs)
Apparently I can solve it by directly using i as dogs in line 9, but if I do it in the above mentioned way, in line 8,why wasn't the interpreter changing the value of 'dogs' to i? I wonder, aren't we doing the same kind of operation on line 9 if I write:

```
 if legs == i *4 + (head-i) *2:
```

and it works fine?

Comment: Because you don't assign anything to *dogs* in the *for* loop

Answer (score 1):

You want assignment ('=') and not comparison ('==')

Comment: thanks..and sorry for the foolish question

Comment: nevermind, happens from time to time :-)